# How can I hide affiliate URL before redirecting to actual store URL using PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
<html>
<head>
<title>YOUR PAGE TITLE</title>

<meta http-equiv=”refresh” content=”0;url=http://YOUR AFFILIATE URL”>
</head>
<body>
<p>Redirecting, please wait. If you’re not redirected within a couple of seconds, click here:<br />
<a href=”http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=2371&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.naturesbasket.co.in%2FOnline-grocery-shopping%2FFruits-Vegetables%2FFruits%2F32_0_0%3Futm_source%3Dvcomm%26utm_medium%3Dcps%26utm_campaign%3Dvcommron”>PRODUCT NAME</a>

</p>
</body>
</html>
```

affiliate URL or my affiliate User Code or tracking code is not safe as it is visible to anyone easily. I wanted to hide tracking URL before it redirect to store websites.

For example, suppose I have affiliate link like `http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=2371&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.naturesbasket.co.in%2FOnline-grocery-shopping%2FFruits-Vegetables%2FFruits%2F32_0_0%3Futm_source%3Dvcomm%26utm_medium%3Dcps%26utm_campaign%3Dvcommron`

I wanted to hide vcommission URL and directly open store website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try hide tracking url and redirect in php like this:

```
<?php 
    ob_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>YOUR PAGE TITLE</title>

<meta http-equiv=”refresh” content=”0;url=http://YOUR AFFILIATE URL”>
</head>
<body>
<p>Redirecting, please wait. If you’re not redirected within a couple of seconds, click here:<br />
<a href=”http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=2371&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.naturesbasket.co.in%2FOnline-grocery-shopping%2FFruits-Vegetables%2FFruits%2F32_0_0%3Futm_source%3Dvcomm%26utm_medium%3Dcps%26utm_campaign%3Dvcommron”>PRODUCT NAME</a>


<?php
header( "refresh:5;url=http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=2371&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.naturesbasket.co.in%2FOnline-grocery-shopping%2FFruits-Vegetables%2FFruits%2F32_0_0%3Futm_source%3Dvcomm%26utm_medium%3Dcps%26utm_campaign%3Dvcommron" );
?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In "refresh: {put count off seconds)" now redirect after 5 sec